# remove full object from Redux initial state when there is no values in the corresponding items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my reducer, I have the initial state which looks like this:

```
    const initialState = {
        isLoading: false,
        events: [
        {
        year: 2021,
        place: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "BD"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "BD Test"
        }
      ]
    },
    { year: 2020, place: [{ id: 3, name: "AMS" }, { id: 4, name: "AMS TEST" }] }
  ]
};
```

I have been trying to implement the functionality of deletion operation. So, when the button will be clicked the "deleteItems" action will be dispatched that will remove the corresponding items from the `place`. This functionality works fine. But,I am trying to remove the whole items from the `events` array if there is no values in `place`.

This is what I have tried already but it just removes the individual `place`. But, I need to write the logic here of removing the whole items when `place` becomes empty.

```
case "deleteItems":
  return {
    ...state,
    events: state.events.map(event => {
      const place = event.place.find(x => x.id === action.id);
      if (place) {
        return {
          ...event,
          place: event.place.filter(x => x.id !== action.id)
        };
      }
      return event;
    })
  };
```

So, after modifications, the state would look like this:(when there is no values in place for year 2021)

```
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  events: [
    { year: 2020, place: [{ id: 3, name: "AMS" }, { id: 4, name: "AMS TEST" }] }
  ]
};
```

Does anybody know how to accomplish this. Any helps would be highly appreciated.Thanks in Advance.
Demo can be seen from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-snow-mlpu1?file=/src/reducers/commonReducer.js:1060-1431)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the places first.
Then I filtered events based on whether the place array is empty or not.
After that, I returned the state.

```
case "deleteItems":
      const eventsPostDeletingPlaces = state.events.map(event => {
        const place = event.place.find(x => x.id === action.id);
        if (place) {
          return {
            ...event,
            place: event.place.filter(x => x.id !== action.id)
          };
        }
        return event;
      });
      const eventsWithPlaces = eventsPostDeletingPlaces.filter((each) => each.place.length);
      return {
        ...state,
        events: eventsWithPlaces
      }
```

Check the edited sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-https-noy9p?file=/src/reducers/commonReducer.js)

Comment: thanks for the answers.I have accepted that one. I am also trying to write a logic on top of your answers where,I don't need to remove the whole events array if the year is current and next year. Is it possible to help me with that.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this is what I understood about the requirement here. You want to remove the events if there are no places inside (existing functionality), but only if the year is not the current or next year. If this is what is required, check this codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-heisenberg-n1yfp?file=/src/reducers/commonReducer.js) for updated code.

Comment: yeah, this is what I have tried for, My bad that I could't make that logic(seems straight forward).thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same logic as in the first answer, but with `reduce` instead of a `map` and an extra `filter`. Just an option.

```js
case "deleteItems":
  return {
    ...state,
    events: state.events.reduce((events, event) => {
      const place = event.place.find(x => x.id === action.id);

      if (place) {
        event.place = event.place.filter(x => x.id !== action.id);
      }

      if (event.place.length > 0) {
        events.push(event);
      }

      return events;
    }, [])
  };
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-smoke-jikkd?file=/src/reducers/commonReducer.js)